# Set bundle display name to version string via run script in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build-script

I'm trying to change bundle display name via Xcode run script if a special condition is met. So far I have this:

```
if [ MY_CONDITION ]; then
BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME = ${BUNDLE_VERSION};

fi
```

I get this error

> line 3: BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME: command not found

Where do I look up this fancy variable names? And is what I'm trying to do even possible with script?

Comment: Wouldn't the display name be set in the `Info.plist` file?

Comment: @trojanfoe you mean I can change the  Bundle display name in the Info.plist file? Sure. But can I set up a conditional result there? I don't think so. Please guide me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah; you need to create a new *external tool* target (I think it's called that).  This script then evaluates the condition and uses `Plistbuddy` to change the value in the `Info.plist` file.  You then make your bundle target dependent on this external tool target.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces around `=` symbol (`BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME=${BUNDLE_VERSION};`) otherwise bash interpret `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME` as separate command and try to execute `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME`, but not found this command. But bash interpret `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME=${BUNDLE_VERSION}` as operation assign a value `${BUNDLE_VERSION}` with variable `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME`.

Comment: Please detail your answer a bit. Maybe with why someone shouldn't add spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity and to officially put @trojanfoe's comment in an answer, `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME` isn't a build variable. It's a value in your target's Info.plist. You'll need to change it there instead.

In order to keep your source control clean, you should put the following script *after* your Copy Bundle Resources phase.

```
if [ MY_CONDITION ]; then
  newDisplayName="${BUNDLE_VERSION}"
  command="Set :CFBundleDisplayName $newDisplayName"

  echo "Updating display name in app package to \"$newDisplayName\""
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$command" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"

  filepath="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist"
  if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
    echo "Updating display name in dsym to \"$newDisplayName\""
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$command" "$filepath"
  fi;
fi
```